# Downloading a file in Microsoft Edge through Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, microsoft-edge

I have to automate a case in which I have to download a file using Selenium WebDriver and cross-browsers.

I already did that for Chrome (through `ChromeOptions`), FF (through `FirefoxProfile`) and IE11. For example, with Firefox, I use `Firefox Profile` to suppress the Download Prompt, like this:

```
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\DownloadCleanup");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);      
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);   
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", mimeTypes);
```

And for IE11, I use `Robot` class to press the combination keys `Alt + S`, like this:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();            
// simulate the "Alt + S" to save file on IE11 when Download Prompt appears
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
```

And it all works fine. Now I want to do this in Edge. But I can't find a combination key for Edge, like in IE11, or a Settings, like in Chrome and FF.

I try manually in Edge, but it seems there is no shortcut to save a file when Download Prompt appears. So, my workaround is go to Edge -> Settings -> Advanced Settings and deactivate this Download Prompt.

Does anyone know how to do this through Selenium, like in Chrome, FF?

Comment: the correct test automation pattern is to use a browser "profile", which can either be a pre-saved profile that points to an empty clean downloads folder of your choice. thus easy to test that file got downloaded, however selenium does let you control the profile at runtime because saved profile files age and break after updates to the browser. Try using https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools for clues

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem where I wanted to download excel files it used to open in the edge's Microsoft viewer.
Now by default the setting `Ask me what to do with each download` is set to False.
However if you want to automate interacting with the particular setting you can do the following.

```
Edge: 101.0.1210.39 (X64)
```

```java
# ...

# Initialize driver
WebDriver driver= new EdgeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

# get settings
driver.navigate().to("edge://settings/downloads");

# get the required settings
js.executeScript('''
var toggle = document.querySelector('input[aria-label="Ask me what to do with each download"]');
toggle.click();
''')

# continue ...
```

The code was converted from this question: [selenium-python-edge-disable-open-office-files-in-browser-setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72254637/selenium-python-edge-disable-open-office-files-in-browser-setting)

Answer (score -1):

Don't do this, you are wasting your time.

Browser manufacturers already test that the browser download mechanism works, if the worst case scenario occurs and that breaks you can't force your users to change browser version anyway.

If you are really trying to check that a file exists on the server side you can do this using a standard http library (Like [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)).  You don't need to actually download the file to check that it exists and you should avoid downloading it unless you are actively going to check the file contents (In which case I would suggest using SHA1 or MD5 hashes to check the files match).

I've previously written about this [on my blog](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/testing/webdriver/2012/07/25/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt.html), although the information is quite dated now.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to download a file on EDGE without Download Prompt you have to change the registry key of EDGE "EnableSavePrompt" to 00000000. I use use this code on C#:

```
        RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge", true);
        if (key.OpenSubKey("Download") == null)
        {
            key.CreateSubKey("Download");
        }
        key = key.OpenSubKey(@"Download", true);
        key.SetValue("EnableSavePrompt", 00000000); 
        key.Close();
```