# Selenium Python Edge disable `open office files in browser` setting

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge

Python: `3.9.9`
Selenium: `4.1.5`
Edge: `101.0.1210.39 (X64)` [driver link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)

I am trying to automate downloading excel file from a website, but due to Edge's default setting of `open office files in browser` set to `True`, on pressing download button with selenium it redirects to Edge file viewer instead of downloading it.
Since I want to automate the process I don't want to manually go to settings and disable it every time.

Any work arounds will be appreciated too...
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is what worked for me:**

```py
from pathlib import Path
from selenium import webdriver

if Path('..\msedgedriver.exe').exists():
    driver = webdriver.Edge('..\msedgedriver.exe')

    # Settings
    driver.get('edge://settings/downloads')
    toggle = driver.execute_script('''
            return document.querySelector(' input[aria-label="Open Office files in 
    the browser"]');
    ''')
    toggle.click()

# continue...
```

similarly you can change any setting as per required.